# Since D3DX utility library is deprecated, what can I do about this legacy code?

Tags: c++, directx11

D3DX Structures utility library is deprecated for Windows 8 and its not supported for Windows Store apps. So my question is, Does anyone know what to replace this legacy code with..

```
std::vector<ID3D11Texture2D*> srcTexture(size);
for(UINT i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO iload;

    iload.Width  = width;
    iload.Height = height;
    iload.Depth  = D3DX11_FROM_FILE;
    iload.FirstMipLevel = 0;
    iload.MipLevels = D3DX11_FROM_FILE;
    iload.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    iload.Format = format;
    iload.BindFlags = 0;
    iload.CpuAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    iload.MiscFlags = 0;
    iload.Filter = filter;
    iload.MipFilter = mipFilter;
    iload.pSrcInfo  = 0;

    HR(D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile(d3ddevice, filename[i].c_str(), 
        &iload, 0, (ID3D11Resource**)&srcTexture[i], 0));
}
```

I have been using directXTK to try an replace them but its a difficult process, both
D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile and D3DX11_IMAGE_LOAD_INFO still need replaced and D3DX11_FROM_FILE is also a depreciated parameter, is there an alternative or effective solution available?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular code is loading images (maybe DDS files or maybe general bitmap files) into a CPU staging resource doing a format conversion and resize. Presumably you are going to do something else with the `srcTexture` array that actually creates the resource you are going to render with. This is a lot of runtime processing, so the *best* option is to do that offline and just create a .DDS file with whatever your final resource should be. Then you have a simple case of using the DDSTextureLoader functions in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) to do the load with complex file parsing, format conversion, or resizing.

If you don't control your resource files (i.e. they come from the user or the web), or you are doing some kind of application where you really are doing a lot of processing a part of the application itself, then you should use [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) instead. See the source to `texconv` for full details. You'll end up calling:

- `LoadFromWICFile` to a `ScratchImage`
- If the size is changing, call `Resize`
- If the format is changing, call `Convert`
- If you need mipmaps, call `GenerateMipMaps` or `GenerateMipMaps3D`
- If you are really needing a GPU STAGING resource, call `CreateTextureEx` so you can provide the usage, bindFlags, cpuAccessFlags, and miscFlags.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/04/direct3d-11-textures-and-block-compression.aspx) as for why there are two different libraries here.